# org2blog/xml-rpc posting fails with "403"

Tags: org-mode, xml

I've been successfully using org2blog for awhile, but it has stopped working in recent days. When I try to log in from emacs, org2blog asks my password as always. I provide it, and the process fails with

```
xml-rpc-request: Error during request: 403
```

I can still log in to my account from my web browser, so it doesn't appear to be on that end. Here's my init.el lines for org2blog:

```
;; * org2blog 
(require 'org2blog-autoloads)
(setq org2blog/wp-blog-alist
   '(("stevenarntson.com"
      :url "http://stevenarntson.com/xmlrpc.php"
      :username "stevenarntson"
      :tags-as-categories nil)))
```

What is wrong here, or, alternatively, what next step should I take to diagnose this?

emacs 24.5.1

org 8.3.2

org2blog .9.2

xml-rpc 1.6.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something may have changed in your Wordpress config with respect to XML-RPC.

Opening the `xmlrpc.php` page in a browser is giving a 403 instead of a GET not allowed response.

See https://testorg2blog.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php vs. http://stevenarntson.com/xmlrpc.php in a browser.

Comment: I finally resolved this---my hosting service had changed some security settings. They say they have "whitelisted" the request I'm making to remotely post to my blog, and now everything is working again.

Comment: For me this issue was solved by turning my vpn service off. I hope this information turns out to be helpful.